# Adding an html form to an existing servlet

Tags: forms, servlets

I have an existing servlet that has a form and takes in data and executes correctly.  We've been given a new requirement to add a page that will allow the user to modify some of the values in the servlet properties file via a web form.

I've developed the package to do this.  I'm looking for a way to add the page and package to the existing servlet.  I would rather not create a separate servlet on Tomcat for this.

I know how to create new html pages in the existing servlet, but I'm unsure how to execute this class file without making it a standalone servlet.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't seem to know what a servlet is, which makes your question confusing. webapp != servlet.

Comment: This is why I asked the question. I'm a newbie with servlets. I'm looking for knowledge.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html

Comment: That's good information, but I'm not looking to become an expert.  I just need to add this bit and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. It seems I just needed to add the additional servlet to my web.xml.  Resolved.

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Servlet1</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mycompany.Servlet1</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ExporterServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ExporterServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>  
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Servlet2</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mycompany.Servlet2</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Servlet2</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```